# Access Windows keystores

Tags: java

Certificates are visible in `Windows server 2012 R2` `certmgr.msc` but I couldn't access it.

How can I access it? I'm trying as next:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ks.load(null, null);
String aliasKey = "MYAlias";
Certificate certificate = ks.getCertificate(aliasKey);
```

Comment: Please be more specific than “couldn’t access it.”  If you got an exception, edit your question and include the entire stack trace of the exception in your question (as text, not as an image).

Comment: thanks for your reply,but exception is not thrown ,same code can access certificate in my pc which has windows 8 and jdk6 but in live server , certificate couldnot be excess.

Comment: How do you know it could not be accessed?